# Elgg Filter which counts answers and likes

Tags: php, elgg

I try developing two filter which order a list of groupforumtopics by the amount of answers and the amount of likes. I know the function: countAnnotations('likes') and countComments() but i have no idea how to use them. I use a switch case and depending on the input i create the $options array.

```
 $options = array(
   'type' => 'object',
   'subtype' => 'groupforumtopic',
   'limit' => 10,
   'container_guid' => $guid,
   'full_view' => FALSE,
 );
 $content = elgg_list_entities($options);
```

Does someone have a tip or better a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elgg likes and replies are annotations. So you have to use [elgg_list_entities_from_annotation_calculation()](http://reference.elgg.org/annotations_8php.html#a2c50117d7de8cc544b2df6c575adc2cf). Its better to ask these type of questions in the elgg community forum, so that it will be helpful for others too.